# The new iMacs come with AMD HD 6770M or HD 6970M. How do they compare?

Tags: imac, performance, macos

the 27" versions of the new iMac come with either the AMD HD 6770M or HD 6970M GPU. How do they compare performancewise? Is it worth its money?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Are you a hard core gamer or a die hard iOS developer? Those are totally different things. :)

Comment: If you're going to do 3D stuff (Gaming, CAD, etc.) you want the fastest available card, especially on a system that won't allow you to upgrade it. That machine is going to be with you for the next 2++ years (my Mac Pro is from 2008 but I have upgraded the video card, an iMac owner can't). So unless you plan on upgrading the whole machine in a couple of years or you don't care about graphics, I suggest you go for the high end, if you can afford it.

Comment: I am a multimedia guy (final cut pro, illustrator, aperture, lightroom, photoshop, Garage band, reason), software developer (visual studio, xcode) and die hard HD movie freak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is 'not huge, but noticeable', maybe 15-20%. I'm not sure what the price tag difference is off hand, but if you're working on graphics apps, games, video - get what you can afford, with the iMac's not being upgradeable in that sense, what can it hurt to do so? With an all in one I'm a big believe in buying what you can afford to get.

That said - if you're going to replace the machine next year? Don't worry so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare these graphic cards at [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/2011-gaming-graphics-charts/compare,2660.html?prod%5B4829%5D=on&prod%5B4919%5D=on)

Comment: That are not the mobile version

Comment: I found at [Tom's Hadrware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/radeon-hd-6970m-mobility-radeon-eurocom-panther,2847-3.html) again that 6970m is little less powerful than a 6850. I also found on different board that 6770m is little less powerful than a 6670. So can make your own compare from [Tom's Hardware Radeon 2011 page](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/2011-gaming-graphics-charts/2D-Noise,Marque_fbrandx32,2679.html)